# How to display rgb data in QtQuick 2?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, qt5, qtquick2, libvlc

I am writing an Application for Android using Qt (with Android Build Kit), Felgo and QtQuick.
The App should be able to display a video which is decoded by libvlc. The problem is, that I do not know, how to display the frames provided by libvlc (format is RGB 24bit). I looked up several approaches in the internet but they were all outdated (e.g. used some OpenGL functions, which are not available in the Kit).
So does somebody knows how to efficiently render the raw rgb-data into a QtQuick Item?

(I know it is possible with a PaintedItem and Painter, but this uses a QImage which makes the process to inefficient.)
(I do not know much about OpenGL, so if your solution includes it, please be so kind and explain  the functions you are using.)